# Error: Wrapper cannot find servlet class com.HelloCedarville or a class it depends on

Tags: java, spring, http, servlets

So I am trying to get a simple Hello World application working using a Java servlet. This is for a Web Apps class I'm taking. My issue is that I keep getting an error saying that my "HelloCedarville.class" file cannot be found.

I have tried many things to get this to work:

1. At first I tried this without a java package, in other words the .class file was directly under /WEB-INF/classes, but this didn't work.
2. Next I tried it using a java package (as many of the answers to similar questions suggested to use a java package). I made sure the compiled java class "HelloCedarville.class" is under /WEB-INF/classes/com, and that "package com;" is at the top of "HelloCedarville.java".
3. I have checked my "web.xml" file multiple times to make sure that I mapped to the servlet correctly.
4. I tried recompiling the java file and retesting to see if it can find the .class file.
5. I tried deleting both "HelloCedarville.java" and "HelloCedarville.class" and recreating them.

I just can't figure out what is causing this error. Here is the full error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class com.HelloCedarville or a class it depends on
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.HelloCedarville
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>driver</param-name>
     <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>connection</param-name>
     <param-value>jdbc:mysql://john.cedarville.edu/cs4220</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>username</param-name>
     <param-value>cs4220</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>password</param-name>
     <param-value></param-value>
  </context-param>
   <servlet>
    <!-- Arbitrary servlet name -->
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <!-- The name of the class you want to run -->
   <servlet-class>com.HelloCedarville</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Must match the same as above -->
    <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
    <!-- maps the servlet to a specific URL in this case it
    would be judah/<your login name>/servlet/RequestInfoExample -->
    <url-pattern>/HelloCedarville</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <!-- Arbitrary servlet name -->
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- The name of the class you want to run -->
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Must match the same as above -->
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- maps the servlet to a specific URL in this case it
    would be judah/<your login name>/servlet/RequestInfoExample -->
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the java code of HelloCedarville.java:

```
package com;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloCedarville extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }   

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request,response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String docType = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
                                      "Transitional //EN\">\n";
        out.println (docType + "<html>\n" + "<head><title>" + 
                           "Hello Cedarville</title></head>\n" + "<body>\n" +
                           "<h1>Hello Cedarville</h1>\n" + "</body></html>\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying it to Tomcat?.. After you write a servlet, you need to deploy it to a container so that the class loader will find your classes.

Comment: How can I tell if I'm deploying it to Tomcat? Is that something that I do in the java code?

Comment: Well it looks like the issue is resolved today. Not sure what happened but it works now, so I'm fine.